# Installed IntelliJ IDEA CE for macbook, when I hover on a function and click ctrl-b, I can see the source code but I don't see any comments

Tags: intellij-idea

I recently installed IntelliJ IDEA CE and the latest Oracle JDK (from inside IntelliJ) on my macbook. When I hover my mouse over a command (i.e printf in System.out.printf("Hello and welcome!");) and press CTRL B I'm able to see the source code but not a single comment explaining what I'm seeing

[Here is what I see after ctrl b](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aqYL5.png)

What can I do to see the comments?

Thanks,
V

*I've tried deleting and re-installing the JDK and IntelliJ

Comment: Attach sources/javadoc to the JDK, see https://mkyong.com/java/how-to-attach-jdk-source-code-to-intellij-idea/.

Comment: Does it work with JDKs before Java 21?